# Xtend: filter an ArrayList of Strings

Tags: java, arraylist, filter, xtend

I have an array list declared like this:

val aName = new ArrayList

I add names in this array via the add().

When I print them, I only want to print specific names (e.g. all with names "Charlie" and working at the department Finance).

In my for loop, I have this:

```
for (m: aName.filter[!CDirectoryFacade::instance.isNameUsed(toString)])
{
    print(m)
}
```

The loop above did not print the name at all.
Because my function isNameUsed() did not receive the string as I expect, but rather it receives the address as a String

```
org.generator.myDsl.myDslGenerator@67bd0a26
```

However, I do not seem to have problem when I do not use filter().

```
for (m: aName)
{
   if (!CDirectoryFacade::instance.isNameUsed(m))
   {
     print(m)
   }        
}
```

Can anyone suggest on how to use the filter() with Strings?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell because your code snippet doesn't provide any types and it is not clear where `name` comes from in the `print` expression.
But the code above should probably read like this:

```
for (m: aName.filter[!CDirectoryFacade::instance.isNameUsed(toString)])
{
    print(m.name) // instead of print(name)
}
```

I could be even more concise:

```
aName.filter[!CDirectoryFacade::instance.isNameUsed(toString)].forEach[ print(name) ]
```

Comment: that was a typo. It should be print(m) since its an ArrayList of Strings. Inside the isNameUsed(), I printed what I have received (what the contents of the "toString" has been). But I am not getting a name. I'm getting this: org.generator.myDsl.myDslGenerator@67bd0a26

Comment: Please share the entire method body. I tried to reproduce but the code worked for me. Which version of Xtend do you use?